How to use different .env files for different environments in ViteJS/React?
I have a standard React app that is using ViteJS.
I want to deploy my app to different environments:

Dev
Test
Staging
Production

I already have .env files for each of those environments:

.env.localhost
.env.dev
.env.test
.env.staging
.env.prod

Do you know what I need to do in order to make sure that the appropriate file is being loaded when I deploy the app on each environment ?
I was experimenting on localhost (windows) by setting those two Environment Variables, but I cannot make it work so far:

NODE_ENV: staging
ENV: staging

How are you doing this ? How do you load different configurations for different environments ?

Those are injected at build time, so you have to rebuild with each set of config. (This might seem like and indeed is a bad idea for reasons I expand on in https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html.)

@jonrsharpe I don't want to create separate builds for separate environments. ...
I guess I will just go with the classic approach that I was using previously back in the days in octopus > Make all important configs in this format {#MyVariableName} and then replace them using a step in my build pipeline. I just really didn't want to put the variables in my pipeline tool (in my case this is github), because all of those variables are not secret at all. They are just different for the different environments.

I could not find a direct way to change the env file in the vite documentation, but there is a workaround.
Install this npm packages
npm i --save-dev @types/node
npm I cross-env

Edit the package JSON scripts section file with the variables.
 "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev vite",
    "localhost": "cross-env NODE_ENV=localhost vite",
    "staging": "cross-env NODE_ENV=staging vite",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test vite",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=prod vite",

Replace the vite.config.ts file with the below code
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default ({ mode }: { mode: string }) => {
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };
  const envPrefix = process.env.NODE_ENV;

  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    envDir: `./env/${envPrefix}`,
  });
};

Place your env variable files in the folder order.

Add a secret to each file to check the workaround VITE_SECRET=dev
Run the server with the different scripts and check the output env variables.
export default function App() {
  return <div>{import.meta.env.VITE_SECRET}</div>;
}

Repository

Configuring env files for staging, development and other phases is quite easy.
create .env.staging and .env.production and modify your package.json file in this way.
 "dev": "vite --mode staging",
 "production": "vite --mode production",
 "build": "vite build --mode production",


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
